Difference between general AIC and AIC according to Stock/Watson
I want to fit an AR(p) model to my data, but the AIC function in R and the AIC definition in "Introduction to econometrics" (Stock/Watson) differ greatly in their results.
The PACF suggests $p=7$ would be optimal. The AIC in Stock/Watson is $\log(SSR/T) + (p+1)\cdot 2/T$ and recommends $p=8$. $T$ is the number of observations and in my case 1257.
In contrast, the built-in AIC function delivers a very different result: Seemingly, the fit is improved the higher the order is. If you calculate the AIC yourself by using logLik with REML=TRUE, p=7 is recommended.
How does this strange behavior come about in the general AIC and why does REML=TRUE perform better in this case?

Hi: it's not a question of one performing better than the other. People use different AIC formulae and some of the formulae include constants and some of them don't. If you're comparing AIC's in order to select a model, then the magnitude of the AIC does not matter. It's the magnitude difference when compared to other AIC's that matters. So, if you're AIC is differing from say Stock and Watson's, I wouldn't worry about it, as along as you remain consistent and use the same function every time. Also, there's nothing terribly surprising about the PACF suggesting 7 lags and AIC suggesting 8.
